# Не показывает background-image в github-pages, а на localhost показывает

Tags: css

Не показывает background-image в github-pages, а на localhost показывает. Пример кода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Воспользуйтесь devtools для выявления проблемы.

Comment: в Linux файловая система чувствительна к регистру, а в Windows - нет, убедитесь что большие-маленькие буквы соответствуют точному названию файла. Ну и путь к репозиторию, откройте в репозитории картинку по прямой ссылке, увидите к ней реальный путь в ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в путях. Вместо `/img/Sec1BG.png` нужно использовать `/repo-name/img/Sec1BG.png`, чтобы корректно отображалось на GitHub Pages.